# I or Myself to use in a heading

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, pronouns

Could you please tell me know what is the correct form of English usge of following sentence ?

> 1. This is so myself ...

OR

> 2. This is so I ...

I want to say like this: **This is so I in this picture**
There is an image online which I could point myself and say that is me.

Which is the correct way of using it ? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say, but the following is idiomatic to me: **This is so me.**

Comment: I want to say like this: This is so I in this picture

Comment: There is an image online which I could point myself and say that is me ...

Comment: This might help: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90511/subjective-or-objective-pronoun-in-this-case/90531#90531

Comment: Consider [waiting longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. You might get a better answer if you wait a few hours.

Comment: @DullaDeCozta Alan Carmack has provided the **exact** answer you are looking for here. A native speaker would say ""This is **so** me!"

Comment: Wouldn't "This is so me!" refer to a characteristic rather than an image?

Comment: It also depends on if anything follows the phrase, extends the sentence.  `This is so I can breathe underwater`.  `This is so myself` would never be said or written.

Comment: @RoaringFish - It's an idiom, c.f.: "Oh, that is **so** 80's!"

Comment: @P.E.Dant - yes, I know what is and what it means. My point is that you would say "that is so 1980s!" about something that had characteristics of the 1980s. In the same way I would expect "That is so me!" to refer to characteristics of 'me' rather than an image of 'me'.

Comment: @RoaringFish I can easily visualize myself looking at a photograph of a clown in bell-bottomed trousers and mop-top, ca. 1981, and exclaiming: "That is **so** me!" But ymmv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If **you** are actually in the image and it is clear that you are in the picture, then you might simply say

> That's me!

If it is clearly you in the picture, but you are doing something that you think is typical of you—like if you are a goofy person, and you are making a funny face in the picture—then you would say

> That is so me!

If there is some doubt that you are actually in the picture, but you are confident that it is you, then you might say

> That is so me!

If you see a person in a picture, and it is **clearly** not you, but you think the person represents you— like your looks, or your personality, or something like that—then you could also say

> That's so me!.

I believe that in each instance, *this* and *that* are likely to be interchangeable.

Comment: I can clarify that it's a typo.

Comment: Hehehe, I'm finding it harder to read everyday. Thanks.

Comment: I hate to pile on, but did you really mean to write "If you see a person in a person...?" Didn't you intend to write "If you see a person in a **picture**...?" Moral: compose your answer in a text editor, proofread it, then post it.

Comment: Ah, don't worry. Peer review is part of the SE structure. I can assure you that I proofread my posts, but as you can imagine, typos slip by. Also, there is a preview before posting, and it doesn't help that I'm very sleepy. 